# CSS 'background-blend-mode' not working as I expect

Tags: css, sass

I cannot get `background-blend-mode` to work either on `figcaption` or on `div.wrapper`, however `mixed-blend-mode` does work when applied. What am I missing?

`figure.card` has a front and back. Front of the card is `img`. Back of the card is `figcaption`. Flip is triggered on `[data-flipped]`. `figcaption` overlaps `img` on flip.

Displayed using SASS

```
figure.card
    --card-radius: 1rem
    aspect-ratio: 3.375/2.125
    border-radius: var(--card-radius)
    position: relative
    transition: transform 1s
    perspective: 1000px
    transform-style: preserve-3d
    cursor: pointer
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)
    &[data-flipped]
        transform: rotateX(180deg)

    img, figcaption
        width: 100%
        height: 100%
        border-radius: inherit
        position: absolute

    img
        object-fit: cover

    figcaption
        color: red
        transform: rotateX(180deg)
        backface-visibility: hidden
        padding: 1em
        background-image: url('...')
        // DOES NOT WORK >>
        background-blend-mode: multiply
        // DOES WORK >>
        // mixed-blend-mode: multiply
        div.wrapper
            width: inherit
            height: inherit
            padding: inherit
            border-radius: inherit
            background-color: blue
            // ALSO DOES NOT WORK >>
            background-blend-mode: multiply
            // DOES WORK >>
            // mixed-blend-mode: multiply
```

Comment: > sets how an element's background images should blend with each other and with the element's background color

Comment: @ray Okay to clarify, 'background-blend-mode' only allows an element to blend it's own background images and colors, and not the elements it overlaps?